# Exchange changes in Git on two different windows PC

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-remote, git-fetch

We have a team of 5 people and we can git setup on each PC. Now let's say Tester1 reports some bug and Dev1 fixes that bug. Now, Dev1 doesn't want to push that change to the centralized system without confirmation of Tester1.

Our Goal is Dev1 can commit that change on his local PC and Tester1 can fetch that commit and test and share the feedback. I have seen many posts but all point to the Linux system regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`git-daemon`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon) is the simplest way to share a repo so someone can pull from it. It's available on Windows too.

Comment: In what deliverable does Tester1 discover the bug? Where did this deliverable come from? Did Tester1 pull the original software directly from a repo and build it, or did Tester1 obtain some kind of official build from a build server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev1 can provide their repository via a network drive, and Tester1 can access it.

Say, Dev1 does all the work under *D:\Work* and has the repository checked out as *D:\Work\Project*. Then they can offer *D:\Work* as a network drive (the Windows term for this escapes me for the moment).

Tester1 can then simply

```
git fetch //Dev1PC/Work/Project bug-fix-branch
```

to access the branch that contains the bug fix.
If the exchange (Dev1 to Tester1) happens frequently, Tester1 can configure a remote for the path:

```
git remote add dev1proj //Dev1PC/Work/Project
git fetch dev1proj bug-fix-branch
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using your methods and we are creating network within team.